# Visual Basic .NET Empty/Null String difference?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to differentiate between `NULL` and `""`.

How do I determine with an if statement if a String is NULL or ""?

Comment: Pretty valid question, not sure why down-voted...?

Comment: `str Is Nothing` versus `str = ""`, there are plenty of questions/answers on SO related to the two. The only snag is that you need to do the nothing check before the `=` check to distinguish the two.

Comment: No it's not a valid question because it shows of lack of research. Also you have two questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nothing` is when the string variable has *no* instance it refers to at all while `""` is when the string variable *has something* it refers to and it is an *empty* string.

To distinguish, you could put the following conditions:

```
Dim s As String

If s Is Nothing Then 'It means it is Nothing

End If

If s = "" Then 'It means it points to some instance whose value is empty string

End If
```

VB.Net also has `String.Empty` which is equivalent to `""`:

```
If s = String.Empty Then

End If
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete because `Dim s as String = Nothing: Return s = ""` will return true. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`""` is just an empty string, but it is still initialized and has an allocated position in the memory as a string with no characters.

`Null` or `Nothing` is a string that has not been initialized or defined, which means that there is no memory is allocated for this, thus the string technically doesn't exist.

To check if a string is null you'd do:

```
If str Is Nothing Then
```

To check if a string is empty you could do:

```
If str = "" Then
```

or:

```
If str.Length = 0 Then
```

However, to check if it's *either* null or empty, you get use of the `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer and the others are all partially wrong because they do not address a crucial point of empty strings in VB. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing#remarks):

> For strings in Visual Basic, the empty string equals `Nothing`. Therefore, `"" = Nothing` is true.

This means that `MyString = String.Empty` will be true when `MyString Is Nothing` is also true. So you definitely want to test against `Nothing` **before** testing against `String.Empty` (or `""`).

Answer (score 1):

you can get dbnulll error if string come from database

you can determine it with

```
isdbnull(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your string variable into this function to test for both:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
```

You can test for null like this:

```
s Is Nothing
```

You can test if it is an empty string like this:

```
s = String.Empty
```

Comment: And this distinguishes between `""` and `Nothing` how?